# Aspect Orienting Logging / Interception Using Structure Map

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, aop, structuremap

I am using Structure Map as my DI container and I would like to use this to setup some aspect oriented logging. (I am using version 4.7.0)

Using RealProxy I have created a 'DynamicProxy' class to intercept methods before and after they are executed and perform logging (in the example this is just writing to the console).

Logging class:

```cs
 public class DynamicProxy<T> : RealProxy
    {
        private readonly T _decorated;

        public DynamicProxy(T decorated)
            : base(typeof(T)) =>
            this._decorated = decorated;

        private void Log(string msg, object arg = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg, arg);
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
        {
            var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;

            var methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;

            var inputMessage = new StringBuilder();
            inputMessage.Append($"Before execution of: '{methodCall.MethodName}' ");

            for (int i = 0; i < methodCall.ArgCount; i++)
                inputMessage.Append($"Arg: '{methodCall.GetArgName(i)}' value = '{methodCall.GetArg(i)}'");

            Log(inputMessage.ToString());

            try
            {
                var result = methodInfo.Invoke(this._decorated, methodCall.InArgs);

                var returnValue = methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(void) ? "void" : result.ToString();

                Log($"After execution of '{methodCall.MethodName}'. Return value was '{returnValue}'");

                return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0,
                    methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log(string.Format(
                        "In Dynamic Proxy- Exception {0} executing '{1}'", e),
                    methodCall.MethodName);
                return new ReturnMessage(e, methodCall);
            }
        }
```

I have then created a helper method to create concrete implementations of interfaces wrappered in the Dynamic proxy:

```cs
public class Factory
    {
        public static InterfaceType CreateDynamic<InterfaceType, ConcreteType>(params object[] args) where ConcreteType : InterfaceType
        {
            var decorated = (ConcreteType) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcreteType), args);
            var dynamic = new DynamicProxy<InterfaceType>(decorated);
            return (InterfaceType) dynamic.GetTransparentProxy();
        }

    }
```

Using StructureMap I can then setup my container to return instances wrappered in my Proxy. For example I have the following working as expected:

This is the interface / implementation I have used to experiment with:

```cs
public interface IDoSomething
    {
        void Work1(string additional);
        double Work2();
    }


    public class DoSomething : IDoSomething
    {
        private string message;

        public DoSomething(string message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void Work1(string additional)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method Work 1 :{0} {1}", this.message, additional);
        }

        public double Work2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method Work 2 Makes Pi :{0}", this.message);
            return Math.PI;
        }
    }
```

And this is my Program

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething with proxy, created through DI:");


            var container = new Container(_ =>
                {
                   _.For<IDoSomething>().Use(x => Factory.CreateDynamic<IDoSomething, DoSomething>("message from DI"));
                });

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            var somethingElse = container.GetInstance<IDoSomething>();

            somethingElse.Work1("Hello");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

It outputs as expected, showing me the messages from the proxy class and the message passed in on the constructor

However, there are some limitations to this approach that I am having trouble overcoming:

How do I setup my container so that every interface is created wrappered in the proxy?

This implementation fails when the concrete implementation itself requires an interface, so is there way of integrating this into StructureMap? I have seen this done with SimpleInjector (https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#interception) but I have not been able to see how this is done in StructureMap, but I imagine there must be a way of making this happen. Maybe using reflection and recursion? (I cannot use SimpleInjector because of its reliance on a single constructor and PostSharp is expensive).

Comment: "I cannot use SimpleInjector because of its reliance on a single constructor". See: https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ctors

Comment: Also see [Overriding Constructor Resolution Behavior](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-constructor-resolution-behavior).